# What exactly is a "silicon oscillator"?

Tags: oscillator

LT and Maxim (both now part of Analog Devices) have product lines of what they call ["silicon oscillators"](https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/12977#/), which are for the most part tunable oscillators with a very wide tuning range, but a higher precision than I would think you could get from an RC-based oscillator. They're not as precise as crystal or MEMS oscillators, of course, but they're continuously tunable over a much wider range.

How do these work internally? Are they actually just extremely precise RC-based VCOs or CCOs (they do seem to be controlled by the SET pin current, not voltage)?

Comment: read product details at https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc6990.html#product-overview

Comment: @jsotola I'm not seeing anything there that answers my question. It refers to setting the frequency of the master oscillator, but it doesn't say what type of oscillator the master oscillator is.

Comment: They are [MEMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEMS) devices, using part of the silicon chip itself as a resonator, rather than using a separate quartz crystal.

Comment: @DaveTweed How does that allow continuous tunability? I thought MEMS oscillators were just as fixed-frequency as crystals.

Comment: The ones that are continuously tunable are just VCOs. I thought you were asking about the products in your original link that have programmable dividers.

Comment: @DaveTweed I would have thought you couldn't achieve the precision LT claims (0.25% for the LTC6907) with an RC oscillator, though, especially using resistors and capacitors made on a silicon process. Is that a wrong assumption?

Comment: Yes. If you read the "Theory of Operation" section of the data sheet, it says, "Where \$C_{OSC}\$ is a precision internal capacitor: \$C_{OSC}\$ = 5pF for the LTC6907".